# how to display the wordpress login and register forms on a page?

Tags: login, pages

I have a wordpress site. Which has the built-in login form with the url http://domain/wp-login.php and register page http://domain/wp-login.php?action=register.

As these pages have no sidebar and headers, therefore I want to display these forms on a page which I have created from the backend.

Is it possible and how will I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The most simple is probably to install a plugin, such as [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/). The more complicated but flexible way to do it is to use [`wp_login_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) to output the form, presumably to a shortcode or something, and then you can style it yourself.

Comment: I used the `wp_login_form`, but when I entered incorrect username and password, it then redirects me to that original login page, which I does not want.

Comment: Where did you set the redirect parameter to go to?

Comment: I have used the Theme My Lgoin plugin to display the login and register forms on a page and then style it. Thanks for the answer.